# How to redirect logs from Cisco firewall to a specific file?

Tags: linux, cisco, logging, syslog

We need to redirect the logs from our Cisco firewall(**SA520-K9**) to syslogd server(it's a CentOS server). The settings are done on the firewall. But the messages from firewall are going to /var/log/messages and console instead of /var/log/firewall.log which is our requirent.

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none        /var/log/messages

authpriv.*                      /var/log/secure

mail.*                          -/var/log/maillog


cron.*                          /var/log/cron

*.emerg                         *

uucp,news.crit                      /var/log/spooler

local7.*     /var/log/firewall.log
```

This is our syslog config file. Any advices ?

**Log Severity > Warning and set to sent to syslog** in the device

Answer (score 3):

default facility used by the Cisco ASA is 20 (LOCAL4):

```
  local4.*     /var/log/firewall.log
```

Comment: Any idea about SA520-K9 ?

Comment: sa520 has no cli. It's not an ios device.

Comment: @Jason Berg: What facility "Administration> Logging > Logs Facility and Severity" ?

Comment: Log Severity > Warning and set to sent to syslog

Comment: Use tcpdump to determinate facility: tcpdump -pn -s 0 -vv -i eth0 host $IP. Facility ... (N)

Answer (score 0):

Check the raw messages and see the facility and the severity that is used. (%rawmsg% in rsyslog ) ... I don't know about syslogd, but you can always use wireshark for that.
(the other way is to check every facility until you get your job done)